# title in intent Action_SEND in an android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting default activity name when I use `ACTION_SEND`. How do I change title from activity name to title that I want to choose?

So far have used following

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, finalUrl);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));
```

Comment: What you want to do..please explain me means tell me your complete requirement

Comment: I want to send url to another apps. for this I have used Intent Action_SEND. but the box which opens I see title as activity name. I want to change the title to " send URL via".

Comment: Means you want to share the application 'm right

Comment: It is unclear where you see an activity name. Let it be a default activity name. I do not see such names when i use this action. You are encouraged to post the complete intent code.

Comment: no when you click on share in google play store it shows a box to select apps but has title of "share URL via"

Comment: You are not programming google play store is it!? You are programming your own app i think. So only talk about what you see in your own app please. Answer my question to the point please.

Comment: greenapps have updated code

Answer (score 1):

you can set title using following

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "your title")));

Comment: Documentation says that title will only be shown for an Intent when the target action is not ACTION_SEND or ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.